# How to get 2 value in option in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my database image:

[image]

On option tag ^ here!

I need Cost and service on Option tag values
How to set 2 values in select tag.
How to do it?

```
<?php
   if($genders=$_GET["gen"]=="Male") {
     $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblservices WHERE gender='Male'");
   }
   if ($genders=$_GET["gen"]=="Female") {                               
      $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblservices WHEREgender='Female'");
   }
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
      ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['Cost']; ?>" id="price"> 
       <?php echo $row['ServiceName'];?>
        (<?php echo $row['Cost']; ?>₹)</oPHPon>
       <?php } ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $row['Cost']; ?> i need to set serviceName and Cost on value 2 $row[] on value option

Comment: are you posting your actual code as is? format your code, it will be easier for you to spot the typo like `</oPHPon>`. On how to have multiple option item, see [HTML select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

Comment: first of all it's better to use id of service instead, because users can edit cost in client side... but in answer of ur question, you can use json on value and parse it in php even though it's not usual

Comment: In addition to the two previous comments, there seems to be a space missing in your second query: `WHEREgender='Female'`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code snippet which you can solve if you look in the error log of apache.

The first select tag and the closing option tag are missing, there are redundant points and space missing in the second where clause.

If "$_GET["gen"]" retrieves data (what I cannot check) and the column/table names are right it should work.

```
<select>
<?php
  if ($_GET["gen"] =="Male") {

  $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblservices WHERE gender='Male'");
   }if ($_GET["gen"]=="Female") {
                    
   $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblservices WHERE gender='Female'");
                        }
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['Cost']; ?>" id="price"><?php echo $row['ServiceName'];?>
    <?php echo $row['Cost']; ?> ₹</option>

    <?php }
?>
</select>
```